# Product count in layered navigation category filter includes hidden simple products

Tags: magento-2.1, category, layered-navigation

I've got a Magento 2.1.7 installation which currently has 3 configurable products, which make up 26 simple products.

All 3 products are T-Shirts, so in the layered navigation, I expect the `T-Shirt` category to show the product count of `3`, as so:

```
T-Shirts 3
```

but instead, the product count is `26` because it is including all the simple products.

[image]

Is it possible to configure the application to only include the base product when calculating the product count?